# Bug in [NSString substringWithRange] if character would be UTF8 with 4 byte length?

Tags: ios, utf-8, nsstring, foundation

I have to check each character in a given NSString for some condition.

When the string contains characters that would be represented in 4 bytes (in UTF-8 encoding) the result is not the character I expected.

```
NSString* oneCharString = [@"" substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

The debugger shows:

[image]

It looks like an empty string. But the inspection shows some value (maybe a symbol for a non character ?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the first character of a string, you need to do it like this:

```
NSString *str = ... // the string such as @""
NSRange firstRange = [str rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:0];
NSString *oneCharString = [str substringFromRange:firstRange];
```

This code properly deals with composed characters.